# Why is it neccessary to change data types when comparing two arrays with PowerShell Compare-Object?

Tags: arrays, powershell, compare

I am trying to compare two arrays and the following code does not work:

```
$cluster="MyCluster"
foreach ($cluster in $clusters)
{$allnodes+=gwmi -q "Select Name from MSCluster_Node" -namespace root\mscluster -      ComputerName $cluster -Authentication PacketPrivacy|Select-Object @    {Name="Node";Expression={$_.Name}}
}}}}

foreach ( $cluster in $clusters) 
{
$actnodes+=gwmi -class "MSCluster_Resource" -namespace "root\mscluster" -computername $cluster  -Authentication PacketPrivacy | where {$_.type -eq "SQL Server"} | Select @{n='ServerInstance';e={("{0}\{1}" -f $_.PrivateProperties.VirtualServerName,$_.PrivateProperties.InstanceName).TrimEnd('\')}}, @{n='Node';e={$(gwmi -Authentication PacketPrivacy -ComputerName $cluster -Namespace "root\mscluster" -query "ASSOCIATORS OF {MSCluster_Resource.Name='$($_.Name)'} WHERE AssocClass = MSCluster_NodeToActiveResource" | Select -ExpandProperty Name)}}|Select "Node"
 }

$passivenodes=Compare-Object -ReferenceObject($allnodes) -DifferenceObject($actnodes)
$passivenodes
```

The above code returns the wrong result.

But, if I change the data type to string like this:

```
$allnodes = [string[]]$allnodes|select -unique
$actnodes = [string[]]$actnodes|select -unique
```

then it works as desired.

But, in [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849941(v=wps.620).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849941%28v=wps.620%29.aspx) it says

> Inputs The input type is the type of the objects that you can pipe to
>   the cmdlet.
>
> •System.Management.Automation.PSObject  You can pipe a
>   DifferenceObject object to Compare-Object

Why can't I use compare without changing the data type? What is wrong?

Comment: Have you run a `$allnodes | gm` to see what the object type is? Have you considered just pulling the data as strings like `$actnodes+=(gwmi blah, blah, blah).ToString()` or something?

Answer (score 0):

While you can pass in an arbitrary array of objects, you probably should tell `Compare-Object` which properties of the object's you want to compare using the `-Property` parameter which can take the name of one or more properties to compare.  Execute `$allnodes | get-member` to see which properties you want to compare.